# isempty is showing Error under validator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am very New in Flutter and trying to learn new stuff i am facing issue on `value.isEmpty` i don't know why it is showing error in attribute validator.

```
  TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
      hintText: 'Enter a phone number',
      labelText: 'Phone',
    ),
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter phone number';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: If you hover your mouse cursor over the marked line, your IDE should show you *why* it's reporting an issue.  In your case, `value` is *nullable*, so you must check for `null` before accessing members.  https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: i am following a tutorial that do it like that: https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-forms

Comment: Your tutorial is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
      hintText: 'Enter a phone number',
      labelText: 'Phone',
    ),
    validator: (value) {
      if (value!.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter phone number';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
```

use `value!.isEmpty` instead of `value.isEmpty`.